# How to copy Android File System from device to my PC?

Tags: android

I'm using Device File Explorer to copy contacts2.db. But I cannot view `/data/data/com.samsung.android.app.contacts` because of `run-as package not debuggable`.
My phone is not rooted!

[image]

Comment: is your phone rooted?

Comment: not yet.........

Comment: You can't access that folder without root permission, (you can access your debuggable app folders but not other applications data folder)

Comment: this seems to be bug in Samsung. I think trying with higer api or other android device can solve this issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37093233#c4